# First c++ file and header LNK2019 error

Tags: c++, lnk2019, unresolved-external

This is my first time having separate files and first time writing a header file, however I keep getting the same error I can't fix. Here are the files:

```
//main.cpp    
#include <iostream>
#include "Bike.h"

/*
class Bike{
public:
     int tyreDiameter;
     int getTyreDi(){
         return tyreDiameter;
    }
}; */

int main(){
    Bike b;
    b.tyreDiameter = 50;
    std::cout << b.getTyreDi();

while (1){
    continue;
}

return 0;
}

//Bike.cpp
class Bike{
    public:
        int tyreDiameter;
        int getTyreDi(void){
            return tyreDiameter;
        }
};

//Bike.h
#ifndef BIKE_H
#define BIKE_H

class Bike{
    public:
        int tyreDiameter;
        int getTyreDi(void);
};

#endif
```

Now if I have only one file and use the class that is commented out in main.cpp everything works fine. But as soon as I try to separate the Bike class into another cpp file I get this error:

> ```
> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int
> __thiscall Bike::getTyreDi(void)" (?getTyreDi@Bike@@QAEHXZ) 
>
> Error 2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
> ```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you defining class `Bike` twice? in the `cpp` and in the `h`, the correct way would be this:
header

```
//Bike.h
#ifndef BIKE_H
#define BIKE_H

class Bike{
    public:
        int tyreDiameter;
        int getTyreDi(void);
};

#endif
```

cpp

```
//Bike.cpp
#include "Bike.h"
int Bike::getTyreDi(void)
{
  //implementation like return tyreDiameter;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So from what you are saying would I be right to assume that the header file describes what the class will look like syntactically and the cpp file just defines the functions of that class?

Comment: @Mick Correct. The header file describes what the class is supposed to do and the cpp file describes how to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jamey. Just one more thing please; what you said works perfectly in MSVS2013 however I like to use Notepad++ and compile using the MSVS2013 command line compiler. When I try to do the command 'cl /EHsc main.cpp' (without quotes) it gives me the same error as above. Any ideas please?

Comment: I worked it out. I just needed to put 'cl /EHsc main.cpp Bike.cpp'. Thanks again.